# «Faz» y «haz» para decir «cara»

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

Para referirse a la cara o superficie de algo, hay dos términos sinónimos que se puede usar: *faz* y *haz*.  En realidad, trátase de un vocablo con dos variantes, una que ha sufrido más cambios fonéticos en su evolución del latín que la otra y que curiosamente ha podido sobrevivir con dos formas.

Dejando por un lado los usos especializados de estos términos (*faz* como *anverso de monedas*, o *haz* como *parte superior de una hoja*), ¿existe algún matiz para la preferencia de una u otra, sea cuestión de región, registro, época, etcétera?

Comment: Yo siempre oí _faz_ para _faz de la tierra_, mientras que _haz_ nunca en su acepción de "cara". Es interesante ver en [el sitio web etimologías](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?haz) una explicación _Su raíz es la misma que la del verbo latino facere (hacer), del que proceden infinidad de palabras como hacer, hazaña, faena, afección, infección, benefactor, perfección, y un larguísimo etcétera_

Answer (score 2):

Ambas se usarían en contextos poco coloquiales, ya que en esos casos usaríamos "cara" o "lado", por ejemplo.

De todas formas, es frecuente encontrarse con el vocablo "faz", pero no ocurre lo mismo con "haz": es un término bastante anticuado en este contexto, y se lo utiliza más bien en el contexto de la física y la matemática para referirse a un haz de luz, o un haz electromagnético, o un haz de rectas, etcétera.

Answer (score 1):

Excluyendo terminas empleando las definiciones especificas (i.e. no `fasces > haz`: haz de luz, rayas, ramas, planos etc sino `faciēs > faz > haz`), parece que *faz* se usa mucho más, salvo que algunos modismos:

Unas frases en que se prefiere 'faz':

- [faz del mundo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+del+mundo%2Chaz+del+mundo&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfaz%20del%20mundo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chaz%20del%20mundo%3B%2Cc0)
- [faz del universo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+del+universo%2Chaz+del+universo&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)
- [faz de Cristo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+de+Cristo%2Chaz+de+Cristo&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)
- [faz de Dios](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+de+Dios%2Chaz+de+Dios&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)
- [faz de urdimbre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+de+urdimbre%2Chaz+de+urdimbre&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)

Unas frases en que las dos formas existen:

- [faz/haz de las aguas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+de+las+aguas%2C+haz+de+las+aguas&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)
- [faz/haz de la tierra](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=faz+de+la+tierra%2Chaz+de+la+tierra&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)